# Has anyone gotten "Replicating the Web database using Azure active geo-replication" working

Tags: azure, publishing

I'm trying to set 2 CD sites (SC 9.3 XM) on Azure (1 in west region, 1 in east region).

I've tried following the steps in this article: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--replicating-the-web-database-using-azure-active-geo-replication.html

... so that I only need to publish to 1 "web" target.

Azure SQL Geo-replication does not appear to support having different DB names between the "primary" and "secondary" DBs.  Has anyone gotten this to work as outlined in the article?

Comment: Yes I have it working very nicely. Did you implement the shared DB?